# Best number of neurons in hidden layer of Encog neural network

Tags: c#, networking, encog

i have a neural network with a structure:
7 input neurons, 3 output neurons.

On the internet it was said that the best results are usully achieved when the number of neurons on the hidden layer is 1.5 - 2 times as big as the number of neurons in first layer. I.e in my case it would be 14. I am using a resilent propagation training method to teach the network in C#.

Training is run for about 100k cycles. I am actully getting better results - the more hidden neurons i have! Not just 2x the amount, but 6x the amount of input layer. In other words currently there are total of 44 hidden neurons defined! It just keeps getting better.

I am starting to get a feeling that something is not right here.. How will hidden neuron count affect effectiveness of the network?

I can keep increasing the count.. 50..60..70. I started with as low as 11 btw and the results of such training were terrible. Please give an explanation why higher hidden neuron count gives tenfold better results and how it affect the effectiveness of the network on REAL data, not jut the training set. (2k records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of hidden neurons is called a hyper-parameter. Nearly all machine learning models have hyper-parameters.  For Support Vector Machines it is gamma and C, etc.  Basically these hyper-parameters affect how successful your model will be at learning the dataset.  Nearly always this comes down to trial and error.  For neural networks you should stick to a single hidden layer (see universal approximator theorem).

Generally the more hidden neurons the better training will go.  However, this may encourage overfitting.  Make sure you are testing the network with data outside the training set.  Ideally you want just enough hidden neurons to allow the neural network to reach a point where adding more does not improve your performance on validation data (data that you did not train the network with).

Answer (score 1):

Just one more clarification. Did you split your data in two parts: training and checking. For example if you have 1000 examples, you can use for training 800, and check you results on remaining 200 examples. As usually if training set perfoms extremely well, then testing set quality increases to some degree, and then goes down. You need to find balance between good results on training and checking set.